# Как сделать систему очков в игре на pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Я пытался сделать систему очков в игре, чтобы когда мяч доходил до конца, он исчезал, а противнику прибавлялось одно очко, но оно мне выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\Two\Desktop\приложения на питоне\ping-pong.py", line 81, in update 
scsore += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scsore' referenced before assignment
```

Можете подсказать как мне решить эту проблему?
Вот код в котором проблема:

```py
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global score
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill(YELLOW)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.speedx = 5
        self.speedy = -5

     def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
            self.kill()
            newball()
            scsore += 1
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
            newball()
            score += 1
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT:
            self.speedy = -5
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.speedy = 5
        if last_s == True:
            self.speedx = -5
        if last_d == True:
            self.speedx = 5
```

Вся суть проблемы в том, что строка `score += 1` здесь не работает, но если я закину её в код столкновения мяча и игрока, она работает, и я не знаю как переделать код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас опечатка в названии переменной. Вы написали `scsore += 1` в функции `update`, поправьте на `score += 1`
Также добавьте `global score` в начале функции `update`

Answer (score 0):

global(это убери ) score - Поставь ее выше всех функций и тогда заработает возможно.Это если просто если нужна то нужно func.score - смотря в какой версии.

Comment: таже ошибка, но спасибо за твою помощь=)